# Android - TextView with 'zero' height

Tags: android, textview

I would to set dinamically the TextView height with an ObjectAnimator.
This is the code:

```
if(condition){
    height = 136;
}else{
    height = 0;
}
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
    mText,
    "height",
    height
).setDuration(400);
animator.start();
```

This works, somwhere, but it **doesn't** set the TextView height to 0, but about 80px. 
Why?

Comment: Why would you want to set it to 0 ?

Comment: To hide (and show) the TextView.. Is there a better method? I'm new to Android :/

Comment: No, you should use its methods. See my answer below.

Comment: Check out my answer to hide TextView with animation. It's simpler than your code.

Comment: See my updated answer. Complete answer, I hope.

Comment: @simone_s1994 are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 2):

To hide and show textview, It is not good practice to set its heights instead do this:

```
 textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

OR

```
 textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**View.GONE** This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

**View.INVISIBLE** This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

To make it Visible again, use

```
 textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**EDITED**

To hide view with animation,

```
 ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0.0f);
 anim.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
  ...
  @Override 
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
      animDrawable.stop()            
  }
  ...
 });
 anim.setDuration(300).start();
```

This will gradually fade your view and hide it with animation.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I set "visibility" with animation? Now, at end of animation, I set the visibility, but there is a "fit"... Height change (with animation) from 136 to about 80 and then go immediately to 0.

Comment: Do you want to have this height change or no?

Comment: I want to set the height to zero, with animation.

Comment: This hides view, but it still takes up space for layout purposes... :(

Comment: Please take a look at this link.. http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.animation.ObjectAnimator

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the `TextView` with animation, use below code

```
ViewPropertyAnimator mTextAnimator = myTextView.animate()
             .scaleY(0f)
             .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    myTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }) 
            .setDuration(400);
mTextAnimator.start();
```

To show `TextView` with animation, use

```
mTextAnimator = myTextView.animate()
             .scaleY(1f)
             .setListener(null)
             .setDuration(400);
mTextAnimator.start();
```

Comment: Like another answer, this hides view, but it still takes up space for layout purposes...

Comment: @simone_s1994 okay updated my answer. I assume it will serve your requirements completely. It will hide with animation and once hidden the View will not take up any space.

Comment: Ok for the "hide method", but I change height to move the rest of content with animation..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to hide it by setting height to 0? If this is the case, why not use .setVisibility(View.GONE)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have other views depending on its location then use setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE). Otherwise use setVisibility(View.GONE).

Answer (score 0):

In my `.xml` file, I used `android:visibility="gone"`. Originally I had this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelReachable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="Reachability"></TextView>
<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/bar_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/insertPings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I wanted to make those elements invisible and not take any space for layout purposes. I simply used `android:visibility="gone"` to have this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelReachable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Reachability"></TextView>
<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/bar_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/insertPings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```